# Encerrar caso digite algo diferente

Tags: java, comparação

Estou realizando uma pequena tarefa de comparação, mas não estou tendo êxito, a questão é simples se o usuário digitar letra ao invés de numero o programa encerra, tentei fazer utilizando equals, mas pelo que estava lendo, serve apenas para comparar igualdade, onde estudar sobre?

```
JAVA
```

public class cliente {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String nome;
    int idade;
    String cpf;
    String altura;
    String tele;

    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Digite seu NOME:");
    nome = ler.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Digite sua idade:");
    idade = ler.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Digite seu CPF:");

    cpf = ler.nextLine();
    ler.nextLine();

    if ("a-z".equals(cpf)) {
    } else {
        System.out.print("Invalido, apenas numero, programa encerrado!");
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Digite sua Altura");
    altura = ler.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Digite seu Telefone");
    tele = ler.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Nome:" + nome);
    System.out.println("Idade:" + idade);
    System.out.println("CPF:" + cpf);
    System.out.println("Altura" + altura);
    System.out.println("Telefone" + tele);
}
```

}

Comment: A meu ver a pergunta é ampla e deveria focar em uma dúvida só (validar se uma string é composta somente por letras ou somente por números em Java). Votei pra fechar de acordo com esse critério. Poderá ser reaberta se focar mais, mas muito provavelmente já foi respondida em perguntas anteriores, questão de buscar no site usando as tags adequadas.

Comment: Entendi amigo, na minha questão aqui aborda estes dois temas tanto para verificar se uma String tem números ou se no numero tem alguma letra, mas se achou  que não está seguindo um foco eu entendo, obrigado pelo feedback!

Comment: Olá, comentei isso porque o objetivo do site é construir um repositório de perguntas objetivas que possam atender diversos usuários, então as perguntas têm esse requisito de precisarem ser úteis para o máximo possível de pessoas. Quando atende a uma pessoa só acaba-se fugindo desse objetivo. Por isso não devem focar em necessidades muito específicas mas sim casos gerais. Agradeço à compreensão.

Comment: Também fazer o [tour] e ler o nosso [guia de sobrevivência (versão curta)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-sopt-vers%C3%A3o-curta) é legal para entender melhor o funcionamento do site. No mais, seja bem-vindo e desculpe qualquer coisa :)

Comment: Tranquilo kkk, irei ficar mais atento sobre o isso, obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o Flavio disse, existem várias opções.
Uma outra alternativa a que ele mostrou, pode ser usado expressões regulares.
Basicamente vai ser procurado letras no intervalo alfabético a-z tanto maíusculas como minúsculas na String cpf.

`Pattern.matches("expressao", variavel)`

Ficando algo como:

`if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", cpf)) { return; }`

Explicando a expressão regular "[a-zA-Z]+":

- "[ ]" é pra definir o escopo da expressão e que vai achar qualquer caracter no intervalo especificado.
- "a-z" significa que estamos procurando letras no intervalo a-z (minúsculas).
- "A-Z" no intervalo A-Z maíusculas.
- "+" significa que ele vai procurar por uma ou mais letras, ou seja, ele pode retornar todas as letras achadas do intervalo que foi especificado.

Comment: Entendi Lucas, e muito obrigado pela resposta, estou começado agora em JAVA e com toda certeza isso vai me ajudar, mais uma vez, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias opções. A primeira e mais simples é você tentar converter sua string para um número inteiro usando `try`. Não conseguindo você encerra o programa

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(cpf);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    return}
```

Atenção que nesse caso o cpf tem que ser apenas os números e não pode conter `.` nem `-`. Uma solução mais elaborada é usar expressões regulares. Com regex você pode verificar se o cpf é numérico, mesmo ele contendo . ou -

Comment: Ok Flavio, irei estudar sobre, obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: @AlefVasconcelos se a resposta foi útil, lembre-se de marcar como útil. Obrigado